# Page background not fully coloured

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I’m writing a small web application for myself, hopefully it is usable on phone. I ran into a problem being that my language page wasn’t fully coloured blue in the background. I tried some solutions, but am not able to get a complete fix on the colouring.

Can someone help me out here?

Deployed version(2nd page):
https://morning-dusk-53803.herokuapp.com/

Picture of problem:
[image: Language Page]

App.css

```
/* #root,
#root > div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #4d92fb;

} */
/* html, body {
  overflow: hidden;
} */
.loginButton {
  text-align: center;
  font: "Roboto Condensed";
  font-size: 6vm;
  color: white;
}

.Title {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Allerta Stencil";
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 17vw;
  color: #fafe43;
}

.languagePage {
  /*height: 100vh;*/
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #4d92fb;
  minHeight: 100vh;
  minWidth: 100vw;
}
/* footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px; /* Height of the footer
  background: #4d92fb;
} */
.container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #4d92fb;
  minHeight: 100vh;
  minWidth: 100vw;
  /* overflow: hidden; */
}

#map {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Language.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import "./App.css";

//Choose langauge, but all buttons go to same place anyway. Could use some styling

function Language() {
  return (
    <body className="languagePage">
      <div>
        <p style={{fontSize:"15vw", font:"Merriweather"}}> LANGUAGE </p>
        <div>
          <button style={{ backgroundColor: "#FF6565", borderRadius: "15px" }}>
            <Link to="/GeneralInfo">
              <span style={{ fontSize: "10vw", color: "black" }}>English</span>
            </Link>
          </button>{" "}
        </div>
        <br />
        <div>
          <button style={{ backgroundColor: "#FD9535", borderRadius: "15px" }}>
            <Link to="/GeneralInfo">
              <span style={{ fontSize: "10vw", color: "black" }}>中文</span>
            </Link>
          </button>{" "}
        </div>
        <br />
        <div>
          <button style={{ backgroundColor: "#9CE939", borderRadius: "15px" }}>
            <Link to="/GeneralInfo">
              <span style={{ fontSize: "10vw", color: "black" }}>
                Bahasa Melayu
              </span>
            </Link>
          </button>{" "}
        </div>
        <br />
        <div>
          <button style={{ backgroundColor: "#9CE939", borderRadius: "15px" }}>
            <Link to="/GeneralInfo">
              <span style={{ fontSize: "10vw", color: "black" }}>Tamil</span>
            </Link>
          </button>{" "}
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>
  );
}

export default Language;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your background color is applied to **body**, i could fix by applying a minimum height to it:

```
body {
    min-height: 100vh;
}
```

**Simple CSS issue**, if your content is not big enough your body will not cover your viewport. As you applied a `background-color: #fff;` to `<body>`. An other option is to **apply the blue backgroung directly to body** but I guess you might have a reason not to do so .

Comment: we don't need any min-height when applying backgound to body: https://jsfiddle.net/uxpc7fze/

Answer (score 0):

You have to update your below css from `100%` to `100vh` will give you desire output.

```
.languagePage {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #4d92fb;
}
```